# get name name of cell from his range google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to retrieve the name of a cell having his range.
this is the range :

```
var rangeOfCell = sheet.getRange(100,5);
```

I want to know how to get his native(A1, AB6,..., ZZA9) name easily

Comment: In your situation, how about using `getA1Notation()` of Class Range as follows? `var rangeOfCell = sheet.getRange(100,5).getA1Notation();`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to retrieve "name of cell" (A1Notation) from `sheet.getRange(100,5)`, please use `getA1Notation()` as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
var rangeOfCell = sheet.getRange(100,5).getA1Notation();
console.log(rangeOfCell)
```

- For example, if `sheet` is declared like `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`, this script returns `E100`.

#### Reference:

- [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation)